# Background image gradient should be as long as the text

Tags: html, css

[Image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1GRt.png)
...I tried to make the title header of a site with a gradient of 2 colors. This title is centered, and the gradient wallpaper is as long as the page, but I want it to be exactly as long as the text.

Can some one help me?

```
.Title {
    text-align: center;
    background: #7F00FF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #7f00ff, #e100ff);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #7f00ff, #e100ff);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Put the text in a div

Comment: Could you share a snippet that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @NicoShultz, i put an image with my problem

Comment: Can you share your html aswell?